# Is there a way to find out what caused an `item:created` event?

Tags: events

I wrote a custom `item:created` event handler that creates an item of template **B** whenever an item of template **A** is created. It works well, except for the cases when the parent folder is being duplicated—then I don't want a new **B** item created, as there will be a duplicated **B** item anyway.

In my `item:created` handler, is it possible to find out whether the item is being created "from scratch", or if it's being copied/duplicated from an existing item?

Comment: There is really no help in the ItemCreatedEvent args, and in the "item:creating" event, you only get the parent element as a small bonus. But unless you have a way, to check if the parent item is a duplicate (prehaps check the created time on it?), there isent a lot of help

Comment: @Sandbeck Checking the created date was a great idea... but I just verified and it's not set to "now" when duplicating. It's just taken straight from the original item, along with the updated date.

Comment: yeah.. Just checked it myself :/

Comment: Just as an off-hand note, other than checking for copy/duplicate you should also look for packages being installed. You can use Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexCustodian.IsIndexingPaused("indexName") (maybe use the master index?) to look for an indication that a mass update is happening.

Comment: Asking the obvious perhaps; but why not use a Branch Template?

Comment: @MarkCassidy Item A needs to contain a link to item B. I believe this can only be achieved with custom code. Although, maybe you're right and I could solve a part of the problem using a branch template.

Comment: Check out http://blog.coria.com/sitecore-content-sync-and-the-update-date-problem for the solution to Created and Updated date not being set to "now" when duplicating. If that can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked through the decompiled source and apparently those events are quite decoupled from each other.

For your particular case I would recommend you to introduce some kind of a flag field (e.g. **IsCopy**) on the template and use the `item:copying/copied` event to set that flag to `true` on the copy item. After that you can easily check that field value in the `item:created` event.

*The solution is quite dirty, but to me it sounds like the easiest way of implementing the requirement.*

Comment: This could work! It also got me thinking—maybe I shouldn't use the `item:created` event. There could possibly be better-suited events, such as `item:added`, or `item:saved`.

Comment: Be aware that the duplicate command does not raise the `item:saved` event - https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-intercepting-item-updates-with-sitecore